# Usecase when we need service discovery service when infrastructure is built with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes and have developed good knowledge about it. however I am not able to understand why and in which case one would use the service discovery tools when infra is on Kubernetes.

This was asked to me during the interview like which service discovery software will you use for microservices. I am not sure why one would need service discovery when in Kubernetes we have `services` objects which can be referenced by name.

Has anyone come across a case, where they are developing microservices on Kubernetes and needed the service discovery tool to say like etcd ?

Comment: I'd read a bit about what service discovery is, because it seems you are not fully familiar with the concept. The fact that Kubernetes allows you to refer to services by name (or more accurately FQDN - i.e DNS address) is basically using Kubernetes service discovery mechanism. etcd is a distributed key-value data base (that some service discovery mechanism uses as a registry) but it is not a service discovery mechanism by its nature

Comment: @CloudBalancing : I know about the service discovery and I know k8s internally uses etcd for service discovery. My question was - will there be any usecase when a developers need to set up their own service discovery set up to support microservices architecture in k8s. You unnecessary downvoted my question.

Comment: It was not me who downvoted your question. I think it was downvoted because it is not a development question rather a usecase/survey question. And yes there could me many more cases for setting up your own service discovery. See my answwr

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there could be many more cases for setting up your own service discovery. One, in particular, is a multi-cluster setup with k8s. You can look at how [Submariner](https://submariner.io) (a tool for connecting several k8s clusters with an l3/4 tunnel) utilize CoreDNS to add a cross-cluster DNS Service Discovery).